# Yii2 Multiple Database Connection : Select database based on login user id, Runtime

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

This is my scenario.

I have a list of all the Clinic using my application in a ‘main’ database. In the 'main', information about each clinic is in a table which also contains columns that for, database name, username and password for the DB. The schema structure is the same for each one.

All these clinics will use the single source code, which I am currently developing in Yii2. What I would need is at the time of login, automatically select the corresponding database, from that all the transaction, must be in the database.

I tried saving Database name in the session.

```
$db_name = "main";

if( isset($_SESSION['db']) ){
    $db_name = $_SESSION['db'];
}
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$db_name,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
];
```

it don't  work i can't access the session in config/main.php .

I can't do the solution because all clinics have the same SERVER_NAME. [Change DB connection Dynamically](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/change-db-connection-dynamically/76412/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 'main' database and then use the main db connection records for the second database:
It is best to configure db2 as a NULL db connection, then:

```
'db' => $db, // default...,
'db2' => [
    // Fill with null values
],

Yii::$app->db2->dsn= 'DSN';
Yii::$app->db2->username = 'username';
# password...
```

Also, first close the db2 connection. `close()` .Be sure to destroy

**There is also a good way at this [link](https://quick-geek.github.io/answers/569092/index.html)**. [Dynamic database connection](https://quick-geek.github.io/answers/569092/index.html)

**OR Try the following**:

```
'db2' => function () {
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $db_name = \Yii::$app->user->getid();
    } else {
        $db_name = ..; params
    }

    return Yii::createObject([
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $db_name,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ]);
},
```

then:

```
public static function getDb()
{
    return Yii::$app->userDb;
}
```

Of course, for db (default db), it may not work. But if tested .., be sure to [close()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-connection#close()-detail), the previous connection/

Comment: So I have to set in all model which is not an acceptable solution. Is there any other possibility ?

Comment: Can't access session variables inside config\main.php . `isset($_SESSION['db'])` always false. is there another solution

Comment: Can not do via `\Yii::$app->user->identity` ? id user for db_name else use params..

Comment: Nope, in the config file, I can't access identity

Comment: \Yii::$app->session can't access in main.php

Comment: I have access to `$ session = \Yii::$app->session;  $session->open();`...

Comment: Otherwise, in my opinion, you should have an authenticate to identify the database name.
Of course, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar configuration, actually we have multiple instances, and an instance may have a main database, and one or more "child" databases.  The main database has a table that defines the child databases, just as yours also has.

I'm assuming the child databases are listed in a table called `Children`.
In the Model for `Children` we have some utility functions that I'll show lower down.

The tables in the child databases are given a model class that extends from `class ChildActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord`

Then any table in the child database uses

`class SomeChildTable extends ChildActiveRecord`

The key element in `ChildActiveRecord` is `getDb` which overrides the function defined in Yii's ActiveRecord class. `getDb` returns a database connection.

```
Class ChildActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
  public static function getDb()
  {
    $childDb = Children::getChild(); // usually set via Children->setChild()
    // Does a connection already exist? Return it:
    if(array_key_exists( $childDb, Yii::$app->params['dbs'])) {
        return Yii::$app->params['dbs'][ $childDb ];
    }
    $child = Children::getChildDetails();
    $connection = new \yii\db\Connection([
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $child->dbName,
        'username' => $child->username,
        'password' => $child->password,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ]);
    Yii::$app->params['dbs'][ $childb ] = $connection; // cache for re-use
    return $connection;
  }
}
```

In our case we have the database user and password in config files so they can be hidden from developers.

In the model class for the `children` table:

```
Class Children extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
 public function setChild()
{
    Yii::$app->params['childdb'] = $this->dbname;
}
/**
 * returns child db name
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public static function getChild()
{
    if( ! array_key_exists( 'childdb', Yii::$app->params ) ) return null;
    return Yii::$app->params['childdb'];
}

/**
 * @return Children|null
 */
public static function getChildDetails()
{
    $childdb = self::getChild();
    if( ! $childdb ) return null;
    $child = self::findOne( ['dbname'=>$childdb]);
    return $child;
}
```

In your code, before you undertake any operations using the child database, you need to find the child record in the Children table e.g.

`$child = Children::findOne([condition]);`

then set the Child database:

`$child->setChild();`

After that you can use any table in the child database using normal Yii code.